# Products won't order by position

Tags: magento2, product

I've placed a products widget on the home page but the products aren't appearing by the set positions. For some reason, it is working on the shop page itself, but not in any widget.

Can anyone help?

[image: Home page showing products out of order]

[image: Shop page showing products in order]

Comment: can you upload a photo ?

Comment: Post a screenshot and mark the issues.

Comment: Please explain problem in detail?